# What does overline mean in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\overline{f(x)}$$

What exactly is an overline used for? Is it the complex conjugate?

Comment: What is $f$ representing here?

Comment: It represents a function

Comment: Depends on context: could be complex conjugate, could be reduction modulo an ideal and a thousand other things ...

Comment: Without more context, "probably," even "likely."  Is this showing up in the definition of an inner product?

Comment: Definition of inner product, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hermitian inner product (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html) is defined by $\langle{v,w}\rangle=\sum_{i}v_i\overline{w_i}$, where the overline is complex conjugate.  This has the property that, say in the vector space $\mathbb{C}$, that $\langle{v,v}\rangle=\left|v\right|^2$

A similar inner product can also be defined for function spaces by computing, for instance, $\int_0^1f(t)\overline{g(t)}\,dt$.  The conjugation normalizes for scaling by a complex number on the unit circle.